# Javascript time-based animation and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, animation

I have been playing around with `canvas` and animation, with HTML5 games in mind specifically and quickly learnt the limitations of just using `requestAnimationFrame (rFA)` and have moved to time-based animations.

I want to maintain constant gameplay regardless of monitor refresh rate or FPS but am unsure how best to handle the animations. I have read through all sorts of implementations but have not found any best practice so to speak. Should I be using a combination of the two?

So far I have considered several options:

- `rFa` only (changes results when fps changes):

  ```
  var animate = function() {
       draw();
       requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  ```
- time-based only (not always consistent):

  ```
  var animate = function() {
      now = Date.now();
      delta = now - last;
      last = now;

      draw(delta);
      window.setTimeout(animate, 1000/60)
  }
  ```
- set FPS on `rFA` with `setInterval` (not always consistent):

  ```
  setInterval(function () {
      draw();
      requestAnimationFrame();
  }, 1000/fps);
  ```
- `rFA` trying to force fps (does not seem very robust, variable delta would work better):

  ```
  var delta = 1000 / fps;
  var animate = function() {
     now = Date.now();
     if (now - last >= delta) {
         last = now;
      }

      draw(delta);
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  ```
- time-based `rFA` (some strange results):

  ```
  var animate = function () {
      now = Date.now();
      delta = now - last;
      last = now;

      draw(delta);
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  ```

Ignore the lack of browser support and the use of Date.now(), I just want to demonstrate my flow of thinking. I think that the last option is preferable, but the last two can run into problems with updating too far and missing collisions etc as well as updates taking too long that the animation looses all control.

Also when a user tabs out using `rFA` only the animation will pause, using a time based function to call `rFA` means that the game/animation will continue to run in the background which is not ideal.

What would be the best way to handle animations trying to keep consistent results regardless of fps, all of the above might be bad and my apologies for the long post (it is just what I have tried so far and am still pretty lost)? even better with with the above issues in mind?

Comment: What's the difference between `draw` and `animate`? What do they do?

Comment: I guess I could have named them smarter. `animate` is just the main function that will be looped through for the next frame to be rendered. `draw` would take the time delta, calculate any objects new positions/states and call the functions on the appropriate context for each object. `draw` is essentially update and render.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense actually. I just got confused by the "*set FPS on rFA with setInterval*" code which cannot be correct. Actually, the time-based rFA should work, what "strange results" are you getting?

Comment: Maybe not sorry, just wanted to show the concept. When fps is low, delta high, collision detection can fail obviously, possibly because of this, objects get out of control (wrong trajectory for example). Same for changing tabs, doesn't really pause, just sets delta very high. As imcg has suggested setting a max delta would help here. Maybe another solution might be to have a separate loop for the object updates independent of the animation loop so objects are re-positioned regularly even if the frame rendering is slow?

Comment: Yes, that might be a good idea. On a high-fps devices, an update before the draw is enough, if the delta gets too high you might insert extra calculations with `setTimeout` in between the draws.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance here, but I am assuming that the time heavy calculations are involved in rendering the context not the, hopefully quick, recalculation of object states. Thus it would be safe to assume that the draw/update function calls, called at required fps, will return fast enough allowing the frame to render from the object states whenever rAF can, whether the main frame loop is in sync with the update loop or not. And this would solve the issues with imcg's suggestion below. Does this make sense?

Comment: You're assuming? Just measure it. And no, I didn't mean to have two unsynchronized loops. Maybe I'll better make an answer to explain my suggestion :-)

Comment: Now I understand, `setTimeout` on animate only if `rAF` is too slow. Clever. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `requestAnimationFrame` available, I wouldn't go against it and only call `draw()` from its callbacks. Of course, you should always use delta timing.

Here's a sophisticated variation of `raF` with a fallback to `setTimeout` for the game logic updates in case the frame rate is too low:

```
var maximalUpdateDelay = 25; // ms
var updateTimeout, now;
function animate() {
    updateTimeout = setTimeout(animate, maximalUpdateDelay);
    var delta = -now + (now = Date.now());
    update(now, delta);
}
function main() {
    clearTimeout(updateTimeout);
    animate(); // update the scene
    draw(); // render the scene
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'ld recommend taking a look at the [HTML 5 - Game Development course on Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs255). I don't remember the implementation of this problem from the course (but there definitely was one), but my opinion from a gameplay perspective is that just using rAF (like your first bullet) is the most fun, even if there is game slow down due to too much processing needed on slower computers.

Comment: Thanks will check out the course. Problem with that solution is on 120Hz monitors the game will run twice as fast and on slower machines, possibly, less than the expected 60 fps meaning that the skill level of the game would change (slower = easier to react etc) and ideally it should be as consistent as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with the last one because it should give you the most consistency across devices running at different frame rates, but you definitely want to force your delta value down if it gets too high to avoid big jumps:

```
var animate = function () {
    now = Date.now();
    delta = now - last;
    last = now;

    if(delta > 20) {
        delta = 20;
    }

    draw(delta);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
```

Comment: Limiting the delta value would lead to odd synchronisation issues, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well everything should run off the same delta time to be synchronised. What this does is prevent the little drops in frame rate from gc etc from  causing things to move too much in one step.

Comment: Why would it be "too much"? Instead of maintaing a constant velocity, the whole game speed would drop for that single frame - which feels more clunky than short frame rate drop. Of course, to run things more smoothly you might want to lower the overall game speed if the frame rate is low for a longer time.

Comment: It tends to be just the odd frame that lags when too much is going on at once, then things get back to normal pretty quickly. With this approach you get a small slowdown, whereas without the clamp you could easily see a sprite suddenly jump across (or even off) the screen, which is at best very jarring and at worst breaks the game.